# XSLT: How to parse out an element into multiple variables

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, tokenize

I am trying to parse out full name out of a single field and store them into different variables so I can use them uniquely as FirstName, MiddleName, LastName.  I am pulling out the name from a top level of a node:

```
wd:Payee/@wd:Descriptor
```

which contains a full name of something like

John F Kennedy

I tried using

```
tokenize(wd:Payee/@wd:Descriptor, '\s+')
```

However, I'm getting an extra element, which happens to be the pattern used in the function:

```
("John","F","Kennedy","\s+")
```

Any ideas why?  Or any other better ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing input, your current code and the expected output.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many names do not fit the US-centric "first name/middle name/last name" scheme. Even if you create a solution that "parses" names like you currently envision, the parsing results will be wrong for a very considerable portion of the input. So the proper solution is: Don't.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without a minimal reproducible example, but it looks like your @wd:Descriptor can contain multiple space symbols.

Have you tried to normalize spaces like so:

```
tokenize(normalize-space(wd:Payee/@wd:Descriptor),  '\s+')
```